# Variable is empty in child component, VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When an event is triggered, I call a function that fills a variable and opens a modal from a child component. But, there, my new variable is empty, and if I close/re-open modal I have the data, so the data is loaded after.

I tried to load that child component after I have data, but no good till now.

**Parent**

```
  <p class="open-modal-button" @click="openUpdatesModal">
     <i class="fas fa-sync"></i>
     Check for updates
  </p>

  <check-for-updates-modal
    v-if="check_for_updates_values.account_name != ''"
    :modalUpdatesOpen="modalUpdatesOpen"
    :check_for_updates_values="check_for_updates_values"
  />

  data() {
    return {
      //code....
      check_for_updates_values: [],
      modalUpdatesOpen: false,
    };
  }

openUpdatesModal() {
  this.temporaryChecker();
},

temporaryChecker() {
  this.check_for_updates_values.account_name = this.account_name;
  this.check_for_updates_values.company_registration_number = this.company_registration_number;
  this.check_for_updates_values.registered_address = this.registered_address;

  this.modalUpdatesOpen = !this.modalUpdatesOpen;
},
```

**Child**

```
<b-col>{{check_for_updates_values.account_name}}</b-col>

  props: [
    "modalUpdatesOpen",
    "check_for_updates_values",
  ],

  watch: {
    modalUpdatesOpen() {
      this.checkForChanges();
      this.$bvModal.show("modal-check-for-updates");
    },
  },
```

Comment: How do you initialize your `check_for_updates_values` data variable in your component?

Comment: `check_for_updates_values: []`, should be an object considering your treating it like one

Comment: I didn't copy the whole code, because is a lot. I tried to copy only the essential here. If I do a console.log in my child watch, for check_for_updates_values , the data are there, but in template is still null.

Comment: Like said above, `check_for_updates_values = {}` in your data then use `this.$set(check_for_updates_values, 'account_name', this.account_name)` cos your object is not reactive to it's properties changing since they don't exist at initialization

Comment: @SélimAchour, you'r right, it with your code too. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really initialize `check_for_updates_values` as an array, this is the problem. According to your usage, it should be an object.

Also, be careful to explicitly initialize every existing key on the object, or Vue won't be able to register them for reactivity watchers! That means if you have a data object empty `foo: {}`, any time you add a property, it won't refresh the vue `foo.label = 'test' // won't render properly`.

```
data() {
   return {
      check_for_updates_values: {
         account_name: null,
         company_registration_number: null,
         registered_address: null,
      },
   };
}
```

Comment: Ok, so that was the problem. Thank you!